# Flutter - No named parameter with the name 'shadowThemeOnly'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm unable to run my app, I already tried some workarounds found [Here](https://github.com/danvick/flutter_form_builder/issues/600) but to no success, any help would be appreciated

**Output from flutter doctor -v**

```
C:\sandbox\AndroidStudioProjects\dataps06>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 1.26.0-2.0.pre.168, on Microsoft Windows [VersiÃ³n 10.0.18363.1256], locale es-ES)
    • Flutter version 1.26.0-2.0.pre.168 at C:\sandbox\flutter
    • Framework revision 299e017e41 (3 days ago), 2021-01-03 06:29:01 -0500
    • Engine revision 121b67fb85
    • Dart version 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-179.0.dev)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.51.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.16.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • K65 (mobile) • K652019012602635 • android-arm64  • Android 9 (API 28)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome           • web-javascript • Google Chrome 87.0.4280.88
    • Edge (web)   • edge             • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 87.0.664.60

• No issues found!
```

**Content of pubspec.yaml**

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  uuid: ^2.2.2
  flutter_form_builder: ^4.2.0
  form_builder_image_picker: ^0.1.2
  path_provider: ^1.6.24
  sqflite: any
  dio: ^3.0.10

  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
dependency_overrides:
  intl: ^0.17.0-nullsafety.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  integration_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

**Error I'm getting when trying flutter run --release**

Note: I have no idea what shadowThemeOnly is or should do, I've seen a lot of people having the same issue but with different files than flutter_datetime_picker.dart

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_datetime_picker-1.4.0/lib/flutter_datetime_picker.dart:215:48: Error: No named parameter with the name 'shadowThemeOnly'.
    ThemeData inheritTheme = Theme.of(context, shadowThemeOnly: true);
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme.dart:107:20: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static ThemeData of(BuildContext context) {
                   ^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\sandbox\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 997

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\sandbox\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: Ok I got it to work by adding /*...*/ around shadowThemeOnly: true 
```ThemeData inheritTheme = Theme.of(context/*, shadowThemeOnly: true*/);```

Comment: Why do you have a dependency override?  That's generally just for wizards.  Best to let the pub solver just do its thing.

Comment: If I remove the override I get an error as shown [Here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70433)

Comment: hmm.  Can't answer then

Comment: did u solved this one? @GaboReyes

Comment: @BagusKurnianto yes, if I remember correctly I was working on the dev branch of flutter and not the stable one

Answer (score 0):

A previous commit seems to break `Theme.of` causing this error as mentioned on this [GitHub issue ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70981). Using the latest Flutter stable version should fix the issue.